# Possible to change git line break to period (for better sentence-based diffs)?

Tags: git, text, plaintext

Is it possible to change the line break used by git to something other than the default `\n` (e.g. a period `.` or period plus whitespace)?

I am asking because this would make it easier to use git to manage text files such as documentation and markdown files. I have seen articles suggesting people to put each sentence in its own line just so that it is treated as one unit by git (rather than a part of a longer paragraph), which is awkward. Hence the question here.

I did some internet search to no avail.

Comment: It might be configurable in some editors. Use the editor as Git's difftool, mergetool and editor.

Comment: You could create a difftool that could do this. I have a C# nuget package, [difflib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/difflib/) that mimics the way git does diffs, you would have to feed it collections of sentences obtained in any way that makes sense to you. Shouldn't be *that* hard to do but if you want to handle some things in markdown that would look like sentences you might need to implement a lot of the markdown syntax handling. If you decide to go down that route and have questions about difflib, feel free to ping me here or by lasse@vkarlsen.no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### interesting idea! But sorry, no.

I upvoted your question because I love the idea. Unfortunately the answer is: *No, Git does not support this.*

As stated in the [git config](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation, the valid values for `core.eol` are `lf` and `crlf`:

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that are marked as text (either by having the text attribute set, or by having text=auto and Git auto-detecting the contents as text). Alternatives are lf, crlf and native, which uses the platform’s native line ending. The default value is native. See gitattributes[5] for more information on end-of-line conversion. Note that this value is ignored if core.autocrlf is set to true or input.

Other related git config settings are `core.safecrlf` and `core.autocrlf`. [gitattributes documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) also says the same.

#### why git is unlikely to ever support this

`lf` and `cf` are control characters with very specific meaning. Regular characters such as period `.` have many meanings depending on the context. In many langauges it marks the end of a sentence. But it means something different in numbers. `...` is often used to be an ellipses, which is not three sentence endings.

So git supporting such an option would result in a mess for many text files stored in a git repo.

#### a workaround: use a git commit `hook` to automatically insert `lf` after every period in your text file that doesn't have one.

It would be a pretty simple regular expression to do that.

By trying this approach you will discover one of two things:

- (a) Cool, it works for me! And my files are still normal text files and my repo is still normal so other people can use it.
- (b) Wow, now I know why they don't support this. What a #$*&#@CRLF mess!

#### why you really don't need this

The reason there are "articles suggesting people to put each sentence in its own line" is because `git diff` used to support only *line granularity* diffs. Line diffs work great for code but suck for prose. Inserting a sentence or even editing one word results in the whole paragraph being marked as changed unless the paragraph is broken up into lines.

But `git diff` now supports *word granularity* if you use the `--word-diff[=<mode>]`, `--word-diff-regex=<regex>` or `--color-words[=<regex>]` option.

Type `git help diff` or see [git-diff Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)  for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind showing how to implement the hook? I imagine I need two hooks, one for adding the `lf` before commit and the other for removing the added `lf` before checking out. I asked a follow-up question here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588989/how-to-replace-with-witespace

Comment: By the way, I'll assume that a period ending a sentence is always followed by a whitespace. And in that case, I would insert a `lf` in between.